# Problem in using svn and buildix

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol

Hi all I ran into a problem in using svn and buildix.

I have a project created in svn as well as in cruise control which was working fine.

Since yesterday whenever I commit changes into svn they are successfully commited but buildix is not able to pick up those changes,

Normally I used to run 'svn update' whenever this problem occurs but now this is not helping for this project.

When I try to run 'svn update', I get

Skipped '.'

and when I try to run 'svn cleanup', I get

svn: '.' is not a working copy directory

I took the advice of some one and deleted the folder .svn in my project but that did not help.

Any help, thanks in advance.

Regards, Jani

Answer (score 0):

You may need to provide more information.

Where are you running this svn update? (i presume it is within the build workspace) . Just make sure you are within the correct folder. And if you are, just make sure your workspace is still functioning fine. (As a preliminary step, i usually run svn info within the workspace to see if the workspace i am working in is pointing to the same branch that I have made the changes into - that is an easy mistake to make). But if you have deleted the .svn files etc within a working build workspace, this command may not be  of much use, but since you have not provided much information, I suggest you try the above -- and perhaps give more details so someone can work from there?

When you say the tool does not pick up the changes, do you mean, the build does not get triggered at all? Or does the build trigger and yet does not recognise the updates? What do the logs say? 
You may get some hints there.